# XAML Style Trigger - Change Style ONLY for Object of with a specific Name

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new XAML however I am given the task to override some styles for certain elements within an existing application.

In my custom Theme, I am attempting to override the style of a **BORDER** control.

From what I can tell (using Snoop) to inspect the application, the element I want to change is just a plain border.

The border also seems to have a Name of "**SubMenuBorder**". Please see the image below.

[image: Snoop Showing Border Name]

Here is the latest iteration of my style snippet in which I am trying to set the border control's Background, BorderBrush and BorderThickness **BUT ONLY** if the control has a name of "**SubMenuBorder**"

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="SubMenuBorder">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>      
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="20"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately the above does NOT work.

The style trigger does not seem to fire/apply to the intended control.

If I simplify things further and just style ALL borders with the following snippet, then it seems to work and the border control I want to change, is styled, but so is every other border control in the application.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>      
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="20"></Setter>
</Style>
```

---

**Further Findings**

I attempted to use a DataTrigger... which unfortunately doesn't work either.

Snoop shows below that the data trigger is being satisfied, however on the second image below you can see that the property of the background and borderbrush are still from the parenttemplate.

Any ideas please?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Name}" Value="SubMenuBorder">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>      
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="20"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image: DataTrigger Satisified]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use triggers to modify a `Border` that is defined in a `ControlTemplate`, with the exception of using an implicit `Style` that applies to *all* elements of the type specified by the `TargetType` property of the implicit `Style`.

You will either have to modify the `ControlTemplate` itself, or *programmatically* find the `Border` element in the visual tree and then change its runtime property values. The first approach, i.e. modifying or creating a custom template, is the recommended approach.

The name "SubMenuBorder" is only known and applicable within that `Border` element's [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

Comment: "The name "SubMenuBorder" is only known and applicable within that Border element's namescope."

It was my complete ignorance to this fact which led to my question. Thanks @mm8